# Apache Virtual Sites with Bind DNS, not redirecting to Document Root

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, virtualhost, bind, virtualbox

I have a bit of a complicated question here.

I have seen many forums discussing how to set up Bind for a LAN and how to set up Apache2 to allow multiple sites being hosted. But usually the Bind tutorials are for single zone setups and the virtual sites tuts end up editing the hosts file for host name resolution within the LAN.

But I want to host multiple sites on one web server and outsource host resolution to a name server. In this case it is all being done from within virtualbox using a virtual instance of pfSense to give virtual routing and firewalling to the virtual subnet. Both the Bind DNS server and the LAMP Web server are Ubuntu 16.04.1 VMs. Both have Webmin installed to help with upkeep and maintenance.

Bind took some work to setup, but it redirects my www.fqdn2.com to the correct servers on www.fqdn1.com.All nslookups and ping to hostname work.

When i type www.fqdn2.com it takes me to the webserver. However, I set up a Hello World style index.html document in the root and am not able to see it even if i enter www.fqdn2.com/index.html. Instead i get the standard fresh install of Apache welcome page. Just the Red and Blue It Works splash page.

Thus, I am guessing the problem is not with Bind, but with an Apache config file. Please ask that I post any config files you would like to see to find the problem.

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/fqdn2.com"
ServerName fqdn2.com
ServerAlias www.fqdn2.com
<Directory "/var/www/fqdn2.com">
allow from all
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have not edited the apache2.conf file.

The site config files are all there.

```
root@www :/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls
000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf fqdn2.com.conf
```

When I go to www.fqdn1.com i am taken to the Document Root of the default site in 000-default.conf. This file has been unedited and the arrival at this page is taken care of by Bind DNS services. Maybe I need to manually add fqdn1.com to the virtual sites list for Apache and delete the 000-default.conf setup? There is no server name directive here. Everything defaulted.

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

If I edit the html of the page there I see it update for fqdn1.com but not for fqdn2.com. This means fqdn2.com is not being just redirected to the DocRoot of fqdn1.com. And since the plain vanilla version of this page has no copy in the Document Root of fqdn2.com, I am not even sure where this html page is being hosted from.

Here are some other configs.

```
user@www:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ apache2ctl -S 
VirtualHost configuration: 
:80 www.fqdn1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1) 
*: fqdn2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/fqdn2.com.conf:1) 
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2" 
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html" 
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log" 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults 
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" 
mechanism=fcntl PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid" 
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS 
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG 
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used 
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used

user@www :/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ cat fqdn2.com.conf 
<VirtualHost *> DocumentRoot "/var/www/fqdn2.com" 
ServerName fqdn2.com 
ServerAlias www.fqdn2.com
<Directory "/var/www/fqdn2.com"> 
allow from all 
Options None 
Require all granted 
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost> 

user@www:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ cat fqdn2.com.conf 
<VirtualHost *> 
DocumentRoot "/var/www/fqdn2.com" 
ServerName fqdn2.com 
ServerAlias www.fqdn2.com 
<Directory "/var/www/fqdn2.com"> 
allow from all 
Options None 
Require all granted 
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>

user@www :/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls 
000-default.conf default-ssl.conf fqdn2.com.conf 

user@www :/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ls 
000-default.conf fqdn2.com.conf
```

Any help would be spectacular, server buddies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also worth trying, is changing your VirtualHost syntax:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/fqdn2.com"
    ServerName fqdn2.com
    ServerAlias www.fqdn2.com
    <Directory "/var/www/fqdn2.com">
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

That should help ensure your fqdn2.com vhost matches the default NameVirtualHost *:80 config apache ships with, and might solve your problem.

I don't think DNS is part of the issue, but you could test this:

- for HTTP, telnet is a reasonable way: `telnet 127.0.0.1 80`, then enter the following, and hit enter

`GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: fqdn2.com`

- for HTTPS, use `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -servername fqdn2.com`

If either one of those returns the data you expect, but a request that involves a DNS lookup does not (e.g. curl -L http://fqdn2.com), then DNS may be part of the problem.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, always looking for non matching entries. Just never sure which one to change out. Will try and report back.

Comment: Well, consider this aspect, and probably only this aspect, of the whole installation to be resolved. Will try the DNS test later on and get back to you on that. Thanks server buddies!

Comment: Sidenote: `Allow from all` is for 2.2 while `Require all granted` is for 2.4, they should never be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed to put a link in sites-enabled?

See `man a2ensite` for details.

Comment: user@www :/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo a2ensite fqdn2.com.conf
[sudo] password for user:
Site fqdn2.com already enabled

Comment: are my server aliases entered properly? it seems that the exactly precisely correct host+domain names need to be entered into the config files or it will behave incorrectly.